# how to make cydia tweak work on iphone 5s and later

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, tweak

i have work on my first tweak and also added 64-bit compatibility but it doesn't work on my iphone 5s but it does work on ipad 4. plzz help me to solve this issue.

here is my makefile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI8IL.png)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you included corrupt headers for example in some headers it shows

```
float functionName();
```

but in reality its

```
CGFloat functionName();
```

so when you compile the project it will run in 32 bit devices but not on 64 bit devices because your code think it will receive **float** while some times it will receive **double** on 64 bit devices

because **CGFloat** is a **float** on 32 bit devices and **double** on 64 bit devices. so you have to check the headers you are using and see if they contain **float** or **double** inside them because apple use their types a lot and they rarely use plain C types.